# VSCode Go disable parameters autocomplete

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

How to disable parameters autocomplete in VSCode using Go? I mean when I try to use new package by autocomplete, additionaly it inserts parameters in function. When type `fmt.P` I use suggestion `fmt.Println` and VSCode inserts `fmt.Println(a)`. How to avoid inserting `a` inside parameters? [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLHem.png)